# tar and ssh large file

Tags: linux, ssh, tar

I have running the following command for 5 hours and still going.  mysql has gigabytes of data, but how can I make sure that the following command is actually transferring data.  Can someone check the correctness?

```
tar -czpf - ./ --exclude mysql mysql-bin* mysql.sock | ssh -lroot xxx.xx.xxx.xx tar -xzpf - -C /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: May I ask, why you don't use `rsync`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can insert the `pv` command into your pipeline to get a report of how many bytes have been transferred, like this:

```
tar -czpf - ./ --exclude mysql mysql-bin* mysql.sock | 
pv |
ssh -lroot xxx.xx.xxx.xx tar -xzpf - -C /var/lib/mysql
```

This will give you output like this, including the total number of bytes and the current transfer rate:

```
 202MB 0:00:13 [  17MB/s] [            <=>                                    ]
```

You can also just run `du -sh` on the destination directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fast network between the two server, you should try without compression (-C).

To limit the use of CPU, you should change the default encryption algorithm used with "-c blowfish" for instance.

(you can also use ifstat or iptraf to check speed of data exchange)